# c++ paged byte queue

Tags: c++, memory, queue, buffer

I was surprised how hard it is to implement an *raw memory fifo*.
That is you push x number of bytes into the queue/fifo and then pop y out.
The byte queue has few requirements:

- Paged. The queue storage is split into fixed sized blocks.
- Dynamic capacity.
- Iterable from oldest byte added to newest byte added. (forward iterators)
- Empty pages are either freed or recycled as new for push()
- Queue size can be computed.

My current existing code has bugs that I don't know how to fix. (I tried and failed)
std::deque<> is the closest STL container but it doesn't provide access to the allocated memory as blocks/pages. It works poorly because the byte queue is used in ring-buffer fashion.

Most useful feature was the queue iteration: `iterate(from, end, [](char*area,size_t n){})` that iterates the queue contents in as large chunks as possible.

Edit: For usage clarification: the memory pages may be registered for I/O operations. This means I can't easily deallocate said pages. E.g. `std::deque<char>` has unspecified page size. I don't know if it possible iterate it such that I know what ranges are infact contiguous in memory for memcpy() type of operations etc.

How do I implement such container or make better use of existing one?

Comment: What is your question? If you need to use a container in ring-buffer fashion, perhaps you really need a ring buffer, not a queue?

Comment: I think `std::queue` does all of the above.

Comment: The problem is that queue capacity is dynamic and the storage is not contiguous. The purpose is to work as a buffer. Once a page is added the page contents can't move as I'm doing I/O into/from them.

Comment: @JATothrim The underlying default container for `std::queue` is `std::deque` which does not reallocate pages in use.

Comment: @RichardCritten except the first bulletin. I need to know what iterator ranges are contigous in memory so I can implement the iterate() function for the container. std::deque<> hides this information. The memory recycling is also important and this something the STL container doesn't provide.

Comment: Using `list::splice` is wrong ? use each list element as "page" (memory block allocated with new/malloc/etc).

Comment: @fana I'm using linked list of memory blocks in my current code. Getting the iterator seeks (advance itr by n bytes) and distance calculation between two iterators work correctly is hard.